Response cookies are deleted on every page reload (Node + Astro)
UPDATED: I was able to solve my problem by reading the cookie from req.headers.cookie instead of req.cookies. I followed the instructions from firebase docs and other resources but It wasn't work. Thanks to this answer I could solve my problem. I hope this can be useful to someone
I am looking for help with the following problem:
I have my frontend in Astro, I am using Firebase Auth to handle the authentication, i also want to implement server sessions by using cookies, so in my server (Firebase functions with express) I am creating and sending the cookie session.
I receive a successful response from the server, and I can see the cookie in the browser (Chrome) cookies tab. The problem is that the cookie is automatically deleted every time I reload the page. I've read and made many changes and tests, but I don't know what I am missing or doing wrong. If I create a cookie with javascript (document.cookie) this cookie persists even if the page is reloaded, so I don't understand what is happening.
I will be grateful if someone can help me with this problem, i already tried to deploy the website and make the requests with https, but I still have the same problem. I don't know why the browser deleted this cookie and not others.
Thanks a lot, here is the code i am using:
<!-- src/pages/signin.astro -->

<div>
  ...Layout
</div>

<script>
  import { inMemoryPersistence, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
  import { auth } from '../firebase'

  auth.setPersistence(inMemoryPersistence);

  const form = document.querySelector("form") as HTMLFormElement;

  form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const { username, password } = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form));

    if(!username || !password) return;

    try {
      const credentials = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password.toString());

      const idToken = await credentials.user.getIdToken();

      const response = await fetch('functionsURL/api/signin', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${idToken}` },
        credentials: 'include',
      });

      const json = await response.json();

      if(!json.ok) {
        throw new Error(json.message);
      }

      console.log(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
</script>

/// functions/src/index.ts
...imports

const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.get("/signin", async (req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.headers.authorization?.split("Bearer ")[1];

  if (!idToken) {
    res.status(401).json({ok: false, message: "Token not found"});
    return;
  }

  try {
    await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(error);
    res.status(401).json({ok: false, message: "Invalid token"});
    return;
  }

  const time = 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

  const sessionCookie = await admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn: time});
  
  // I am using secure:false to test in localhost but I have the same problem 
  res.cookie("__session", sessionCookie, {maxAge: time, httpOnly: true, secure: false});

  // I tried with https and i have the same problem
  //res.cookie("__session", sessionCookie, {maxAge: time, httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: 'none'});

  res.json({ok: true, session: sessionCookie});
});

